# Regain access to Apple ID protected by 2-step verification after losing access to trusted device

Tags: apple-id

I have not used my Apple ID in a while and would like to resume using it. The Apple ID in question is protected by two-step verification. Unfortunately I have lost access to the linked SIM card which was used to receive verification SMS.

In the absence of the SIM card, I am unable to access the account page, neither am I able to perform account recovery. It is not possible for me to regain access to the SIM card.

How do I regain access to my Apple ID in this case?

Comment: “Trusted device” and “sim” aren’t the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

You can take the following approach one-by-one:

1. If you have lost access to the phone number associated with your Apple ID for 2-step verification, you can regain access to your account as long as you remember the password and you happen to have access to your account **Recovery key**.

   You'll need to visit [Apple ID account page](https://appleid.apple.com/), enter your Apple ID and password, and on **Verify Your Identity screen**, you'll need to select **Can’t access your trusted devices?** You'll be asked to enter your Recovery Key.

   For detailed instructions, you can refer Apple Support article, [If you can‘t sign in with two-step verification using your Apple ID](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT202649).
2. If you do not have the your account **Recovery Key**, your second resort will be to contact Apple Support. You can find the contact information for your region, by referring to this Apple Support document, [Contact Apple for help with Apple ID account security](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT204169).